# How much to charge for being a math tutor?

Tags: soft-question

I have been requested by some people I know fairly well to tutor their son in math. He is going into 9th grade, so it's not super-fancy stuff.

Some background: I graduated fairly recently from college with a bachelor's in engineering, and I have a programming job that pays well enough. They approached me, not the other way around, and I've never tutored anyone in anything before.

How much should I charge?

Edit: I ought to mention that they will be paying for transportation, so that's not an issue here.

<sub>I hope this isn't too far offtopic.</sub>

Comment: This isn't a math question. I don't know if M.SE is the right place for you to get an answer on this.

Comment: Voted to close as off topic.

Comment: probably next to nothing given the existence of websites like this

Comment: I thought this might be off topic. Thanks for all your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a highly location dependent question.

What I suggest is to ask around *more locally*. Is there a near by university?  What does the average tutor there charge (there are usually signs or sites online).  Also what do you feel your time is worth?  Maybe you require it to pay as much per hour as your programming job, maybe not, maybe more.

Also, if you google this question you get quite a few results and already existing forum posts.

(For what its worth, if I remember, the posters at my university usually charged somewhere between 25-35 dollars, and those students had bachelor degrees.  Again different places are certainly very different.)

Comment: Thanks. I live in the SF Bay Area, but I've never been to or by any of the universities here. It certainly doesn't have to pay as much as my day job.

Comment: @Cajun:  There are many existing online forums with answers to this type of question.  I suggest google searching, and browsing the first 50 or so pages.  Here is one I found interesting: http://ask.metafilter.com/75268/Whats-the-going-rate-for-tutoring  Unfortunately, this question is off topic for Math Stack Exchange.